# Prove that a function is not differentiable on $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> Prove that the function $f(x)=\sin(|x|)+x\cos x$ is not differentiable on $x=0$.

I've tried to use the definition of a differentiable function but I am getting stuck.

It is kind of obvious that the problem comes from $|x|$ because it is not differentiable.

Comment: That's not much of a proof. The same argument would show that $|x|^2$ is not differentiable, but it _is_ differentiable.

Comment: Well yeah i thought that this it the problem but i thought that there might be a mor mathamatical solution to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition (since $f(0)=0$) 
$$f^{'}(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
In your case
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(|x|)}{x}+\cos(x)$$
As $x \to 0^{+}$, this approaches $2$, but as $x \to 0^{\bf -}$, this approaches $0$.

Note the change in behavior is due to absolute value.
$$\frac{\sin(|x|)}{x}=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} & \text{if } x >0\\
\frac{-\sin(x)}{x} & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}$$